# Find and replace in XML file in vi

Tags: command-line, replace, find, filetype-xml

I have an .xml file which contains many times the following web beacon

```
<span lang="EN" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO</span>
```

I would like to make a "Find&Replace": each web beacon of this type (**the text inside may differ**)  should be replace by

```
<span lang="FR" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO</span>
<span lang="EN" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO</span>
```

In short I copy each "EN" web beacon into the same web beacon except I would replace "EN" by "FR".

Example.

At first, my file looks like:

```
<text><![CDATA[<p><span lang="EN" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO1</span><span lang="FI" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO1</span><span lang="RU" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO1</span></p>]]></text>
<text><![CDATA[<p><span lang="EN" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO2</span><span lang="FI" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO2</span><span lang="RU" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO2</span></p>]]></text>
```

and should be edited as

```
text><![CDATA[<p><span lang="FR" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO1</span><span lang="EN" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO1</span><span lang="FI" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO1</span><span lang="RU" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO1</span></p>]]></text>
text><![CDATA[<p><span lang="FR" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO2</span><span lang="EN" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO2</span><span lang="FI" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO2</span><span lang="RU" class="multilang">ANY TEXT TOTO2</span></p>]]></text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
:g/lang="EN"/s%^\(.\{-}\)\(<span .\{-}</span>\)%\1\2\2%|s%lang="EN"%lang="FR"%
```

Breakdown:

- `g/lang="EN"/` for all lines that contain `lang="EN"`
- `s%^\(.\{-}\)\(<span .\{-}</span>\)%\1\2\2%`

  - `^\(.\{-}\)` match the shortest possible prefix
  - `\(<span .\{-}</span>\)` match from first `<span` to first `</span>`
  - `\1\2\2` replace with the prefix (first `\(...\)`) and two times the matched span (second `\(...\)`).
- `s%lang="EN"%lang="FR"%` finally replace first `lang="EN"` with `lang="FR"`

Comment: In fact I have some other web beacon in front of each line containing <span lang="EN".
What is the command to match from the first <span> instead the whole beginning of the line ?

Comment: @Smilia Updated